# Must apt-get install software-properties-common precede ppa:X?

Tags: apt, upgrade, scripts, ppa, syntax

This is how I currently install some basic software in my Ubuntu 18.04 server environment. I am afraid I might have some redundancy here:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible ppa:certbot/certbot

apt-get upgrade unattended-upgrades sshguard curl wget git ansible zip unzip tree mc lamp-server^ python-certbot-apache
```

Must `apt-get install software-properties-common` precede the two `ppa`s there?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` actually doesn’t install anything new: `under no circumstances are (…) packages not already installed retrieved and installed` I think it even ignores the package names and upgrades everything – what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @dessert all I try here is to have all needed prerequisites to install `ansible` and `python-certbot-apache` properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `ansible` and `python-certbot-apache` are available from the official sources and you only need step 3 to install them. The PPAs have newer versions of the software though, so I assume you want to use them nevertheless.

`apt` takes care of dependencies itself, you usually don‘t need to do anything about it, and this includes software from PPAs. All you need to do is:

1. Add your PPA(s):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible ppa:certbot/certbot
   ```
2. Update the software sources so that `apt` knows about the new software:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the software you want:

   ```
   sudo apt install ansible python-certbot-apache
   ```

`apt` will announce you if there is other software needed, and install it directly in the third step.

---

There may be the case the (preinstalled) command `add-apt-repository` is *not* available on your system, in which case the first step will throw an error. Only then you need to install the `software-properties-common` package (once) before following the above steps:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```